# How to get current item in listview in androidstudio project and pass date to other activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I need help for get current item from listview and pass data to other activity in android studio 
(I need pass id , name to register.java ) for register tour 
Could anyone help me step by step out this?

mainactivity code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "http://host.com/android/index3.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    // We first check for cached request
    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        // fetch the data from cache
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        // making fresh volley request and getting json
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        // Adding request to volley request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
}
/**
 * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
 * */
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");
        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));
            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setprice(feedObj.getString("price"));
            item.setintro(feedObj.getString("intro"));
            item.setdate1(feedObj.getString("date1"));
            item.setdate2(feedObj.getString("date2"));
            item.setvalance(feedObj.getString("valance"));
            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);
            feedItems.add(item);
        }
        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_main: return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
}
```

and feeditem.java code is:

```
public class FeedItem {
private int id;
private String name, price, image, intro, date1,date2,valance, url;

public FeedItem() {
}

public FeedItem(int id, String name, String image,String price, String intro,
                String date1, String date2,String valance, String url) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.price = price;
    this.intro = intro;
    this.date1 = date1;
    this.date2 = date2;
    this.valance = valance;
    this.url = url;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImge() {
    return image;
}

public void setImge(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getprice() {
    return price;
}

public void setprice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getintro() {return intro;}

public void setintro(String intro) {
    this.intro = intro;
}

public String getdate1() {
    return date1;
}

public void setdate1(String date1) {
    this.date1 = date1;
}
public String getdate2() {
    return date2;
}

public void setdate2(String date2) {
    this.date2 = date2;
}
public String getvalance() {
    return valance;
}

public void setvalance(String valance) {
    this.valance = valance;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ...
    ...
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YOUR_ACTIVITY.class);  //YOUR_ACTIVITY is where you want to pass data
            FeedItem feedItem = (FeedItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("feed_item", feedItem);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ...
    ...
}
```

In YOUR_ACTIVITY `Activity`, get object from intent like below

```
public class YOUR_ACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FeedItem feedItem = (FeedItem) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("feed_item");
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

Don't forget to implement `Serializable` in your `FeedItem` class.

```
public class FeedItem implements Serializable {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks by replay. but when add your code  when click in listview nothapend!